# Second Isomorphism Theorem and Third Isomorphism Theorem

Tags: ring-theory

could someone point me to a book with the proofs of the theorems below:

- According to Isomorphism Theorem: If I and J are ideals of R, then $J / (I \cap J) = IJ / I$.
- Third isomorphism theorem: If I and J are ideal for an R ring with $I \subset J$, so $I/J$ is an ideal of $R/J$ and $(R / J) / (I / J) = R / I$.

Comment: Lang proves both of these as a corollary of the first isomorphism theorem in his graduate text "Algebra"

Comment: Thank you, Andres.

Comment: In your first statement, it is actually $J / (I \cap J) \cong (I + J) / I$. And in your second statement you have to replace $=$  by ${\cong}$.